# Concept of Benchmarking in C#?

Tags: c#

Please tell me something about Benchmarking in C#..What the different code benchmarking techniques are??
How to benchmark our own code based on speed and memory usage??
Please help me guys..Thanks

Comment: Benchmarking is comparing the perf of different programs that do the same thing.  Since you only talk about your own code, the proper term here is "profiling".  Lots and lots of questions about that already, use the search box in the upper right corner.

Comment: Thans for the clarification Hans. I didn't realize that there was a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Red Gate's ANTS is the memory/performance profiling tools that I use.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/

Answer (score 0):

There is also the dotTrace from JetBrains:

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Comment: Yea, I've found the ANTS profiler to be a much better tool in terms of ease of use and analysis hints. While I feel that way about dotTrace, I use dotCover for its resharper integration.